# How to check for a nearby target in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, distance, p5.js

I made a function called `CheckForTarget()` to check the closest target to an object. I used the `p5.js`function `dist()` to calculate the distance but the answer to this calculation results as `NaN`.

```
checkForTarget() {
    let closest;
    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < food_amount; i++) {
        let d = dist(this.x, this.y, food[i].pos.x, food[i].pos.y);
        console.log(d);
        if (d < this.sense && d < closest) {
            closest = d;
            index = i;
        }

    }

}
```

Expected result: a certain distance between 0 and the radius

Actual result: `NaN`

Added:

```
class Dot {
    constructor() {
        this.pos = createVector(width / 2, height / 2);
        this.vel = createVector();
        this.acc = createVector();
```

Comment: Can you show where `this.x, this.y and food` are declared and inizialized?

Comment: Probably either one of the following is `undefined`: `this.x, this.y, food[i].pos.x, food[i].pos.y`

Comment: @OnurAri Exactly, I think so too

Comment: I see what i did wrong, i said this.x and this,y instead of this.pos.x and this.pos.y. Thanks